# Upload files from linux vps to web host

Tags: linux, logging, vps

I want to somehow automatically upload files every 5 minutes. I want to upload/transfer the files from my linux vps to my web host.

What I'm trying to do is upload some logs files generated on my vps to my web host so administrators can access it with an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use wput along with cron to ftp files to your host

```
wput [options] [file]... ftp://[username[:password]@]hostname[:port][/[path/][file]]
```

You will probably have to install the tool as its not included by default (at least it hasnt been on most of my installs)

Comment: probably a permissions issue, otherwise path is wrong i believe thats the only reason to get that error.

Comment: wput Hun/log*.txt ftp://rabci:pass@domain.com/public_html/logs - The files named log1.txt, log2.txt, log3.txt should be uploaded to public_html/logs/

Comment: Managed to fix it but, the files are appended in one file called cdlogs, I want that to be a directory.

Comment: use a ending / for it to be used as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set up a cron job for this. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) page for this has a nice overview of how the crontab file is laid out. However, you should check your distribution's documentation for better information (they could be using a different version or a completely different cron daemon).

The line you'd add to the crontab would look something like this:

```
*/5 * * * * <user to run command as> <your command>
```

See also: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: My question is how to upload it, not how to automate it.

Comment: In that case, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your web host provides SCP or FTP servers to allow you to copy files over. How do you transfer files when you're uploading your web site files?

If it's ftp, use the ftp command:

```
ftp -u user:password@host/destination_folder/ sourcefile.txt
```

If it's scp, use the scp command:

```
scp foobar.txt username@host:/some/remote/directory
```